# Help with determining the dimension change in the xyz direction of a component under a load?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, mathematics

I'm stuck on this question. I got the first part right which is to work out the dimension change in the x direction but I got the y and z directions wrong. I had to submit this online and it doesn't show what you did wrong so I'm really frustrated on why I got this wrong I was hoping someone could correct me. Since I put my answers online I left the negatives in both my y and z values which might be why I got it wrong I just wanted someone to help to see if I have actually done something wrong.

[image]

I forgot to add in my diagram the length of the x which is 200mm sorry. It's in my working though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include the stress applied to the Y direction (your drawing shows Py = 10 kN) this contributes to the strain in the Y direction.

Also If you take the Y direction as "up" (as you have with the load 10 kN) then your Z dimension is out of the page, when you calculate the displacement in those directions it looks like you got the signs mixed up.

Remember the load in the Y direction will cause expansion in Y and contraction in X and Z. You need to add up all these effects in each direction.

Comment: Oh I totally forgot that how would I do that though ? and for the Z direction ?  So would I work out the stress in the y direction and then do the same as x ?  How would I do this for Z though ?  Also I'm still not sure what you mean by how I got the signs mixed up ? Could you explain that ? Thank you so much for the help I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry I also wanted to ask what areas would I use for y and z ?

Comment: Okay so you have stress in the X, you solved it right. Find the strain in each direction due to that stress. Now do the same with the Y direction, find the stress in Y and the strain in all 3 directions. After this add the strain up in each direction. Then calculate the change in length in each direction. .... As for the signs, you need to multiple the strain in a given direction, by the length of the body IN THAT direction. To me it looks like your length in the y direction (Ly =30 mm) this should be multiplied by the strain ey to find change in length in Y.

Comment: Okay thank you so to work out the stress in y would my area be 200 x 20 though ?

Comment: Yes that is the projected area in the X-Z plane. So your length in Y is again 30mm.

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you are saying now so thank you but one last question so should both my answer for y and z they should not be negative at all ? I think I have done what you have told me to do and I no longer get negatives ? It's just because my lecturer put a negative in his example in a lecture although he used a different method ?

Comment: Okay so sign convention is something that we define. But we must be consistent. So lets assume that Expansion is positive sign and Contraction is Negative sign. Just look at the case of force in X direction, you will get expansion in X, and contraction in Y and Z. I recommend that you visualize these deformations and it is easier to keep your sign convention straight. To illustrate, the force in Y will cause a positive strain in Y, but the force in X causes a negative strain in Y. Add the positive and negative strains in Y from these effects to get net strain in Y....

Comment: I understand what you are saying now i do have one more question sorry otherwise i know what to do.  How would I work out the stress in the z direction though ? That's the only thing confusing me now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91836/discussion-between-shadowman-and-cinna).